VBA MS Word - Prevent Header from duplicating (LinkToPrevious not working)
I am trying to add a header to just one page in a word document. I have activedocument.Sections(10).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False, but whatever I put in the header is added to all other pages. I have tried looping through all headers with
For Each sec In doc.Sections
     for each hdr in sec.headers
          hdr.LinkToPrevious = False
     next
Next

, but whatever I put in one header is being placed in all.

If you're running that code after populating the header, you need to then delete the preceding Section's header content.

@macropod The previous header has content in it. How do I keep the preceding header's content while creating new header content for each page?


Create the new Section. 2. Unlink the new Section's header(s) from the previous Section. 3. Delete/overwrite the new Section's header content.


@macropod 1. What if the new section is already created? 3. How does deleting the header content prevent this from happening?

Instead of having all this back & forth in the comments, you need to explain clearly what you're trying to do in the question itself, including supplying the code you're using. The snippets you've posted provide no context regarding what's being done when or what the expected result is.
